# A Hamilton graph having a Hamilton cycle that traverse an edge more than once.

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

I was asked to draw a Hamilton graph having a Hamilton cycle that traverse an edge more than once.

My first impression of this question was: what? *I mean if we are not allowed to visit a vertex more than once doesn't it mean we are not allowed to traverse an edge more than once*. But then I thought of the following solution. Consider the graph

[image: G]

Then this is a Hamilton graph with a Hamilton cycle 
$$
v_1,e_1,v_2,e_1,v_1
$$

> My question: First, am I right? Can you draw a *different* Hamilton graph having a Hamilton cycle that traverse an edge more than once? By a *different* I mean a graph that does not contain the given graph above as its subgraph?

Comment: I think you were right the first time. The graph you drew is not a Hamilton cycle because it's not a cycle. Yes, if the definition of "cycle" is formulated carelessly, then that graph might be considered a "cycle", but not if cycle is defined correctly.

Comment: @bof: So, are implying that there is no such graph?

Comment: That would be my answer, but if your textbook's definition of a "cycle" allows a "cycle" with two vertices joined by one edge, you have to go with that. (For me, a cycle with two vertices would also have to have two edges.) What book are you using for graph theory?